# Linq select multiple columns, condition not working

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to extract the "Connection and Seal" entries in case both aren't null or "". My attempt was following:

```
var fromElements = from el in l
                           where el.from != "" && el.from != null
                           select l.Select(i => new
                           {
                               i.Connection,
                               i.Seal
                           });
```

As far as I know, the problem is that each match creates a new object with all the input. Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If Connection and Seal are properties elements in IEnumerable  ' l '

```
var fromElements = from el in l
                               where el.From != "" && el.From != null
                               select new
                               {
                                   el.Connection,
                                   el.Seal
                               }
```

As I understood you wanted make select inside select which is not needed